# How to delete empty folders with some exceptional folders in shell script?

Tags: shell

For example:
I have folder keep1, sub folder keep2 and sub folder of folder keep2 : keep3:

```
Keep1(not empty)
    Keep2(not empty)
        Keep3(empty)
```

Currently I'm using:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /b /ad ^| sort /r') do rd "%%i"
```

which deletes all empty folders but I don't want to delete some folders.In above example, I want to keep folder `Keep3`which is empty.

Comment: why dont you do a mkdir after deleting that folder

Comment: Is Perl an option? File::Find is quite good.

Comment: @code frenzy - there could be multiple folders at different locations, it would be tedious to create folder every time it deletes one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you not do use find?

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /b /ad ^| sort /r ^| find /V "Keep3"') do rd "%%i"
```

?

**EDIT**
I've seen you might have multiple places you need to skip, so you could use http://www.computerhope.com/findstr.htm findstr

ie if you have to ignore Keep3 and Keep4 then its

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /b /ad ^| sort /r ^| findstr /V "Keep3 Keep4"') do rd "%%i"
```

It also as (basic) regex capabilities